# Como delimitar área de plotagem no python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

A figura está cortando as legendas, como arrumo isso?

```
# Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make data
group_names=['0,89% - Tração Animal e Propulsão Humana',
                       '45,08% - Passageiro e Misto',
                       '2,77% - Não Identificado',
                       '2,24% - Coletivos', 
                       '12,76% - Motos e Similares', 
                       '0,07% - Tratores', 
                       '25,13% - Caminhões', 
                       '0,05% - Carga independente',              
                       '11,01% - Carga e Misto']

group_size=[ 211, 10747,661,    535,   3041, 16,  5990,    13,  2626]

# Create colors
a, b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i =[plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd, 
                            plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd, plt.cm.YlOrRd,]

# First Ring (outside)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')

mypie, _ = ax.pie(group_size, radius=1.3, labels=group_names, colors=[a(0.3),  b(0.9),  c(0.5), d(0.4), e(0.7), 
                                                                                                             f(0.2),  g(0.8),  h(0.1), i(0.6)] )
plt.setp(mypie, width=0.5, edgecolor='white')

#plt.legend(loc=(1.0,0.2))

plt.savefig('meuGrafico.png', dpi=300)

# show it
plt.show()
```

[image: Figura]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta passar o parâmetro `bbox_inches='tight'`:

```
plt.savefig('meuGrafico.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Novamente obrigado rapaz.